# Fixed position doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: css, html, css-position

Right column fixed position works on Opera & Firefox but not on Chrome, any solution?

```
#rightcolumn { 
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
float: right;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
height: auto;
width: 300px;
display: inline;
position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a test case? Your CSS should work just fine.

Comment: Describe your problem. Show all of your relevant code.

Comment: What are you applying this selector to, and what do you mean by "Doesn't work" - Could you create a jsFiddle to show what you mean?

Comment: #leftcolumn { 
 height: auto;
 width: 600px;
 float: left;
}
#rightcolumn { 
 position: fixed;
 float: right;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: auto;
 width: 300px;
 display: inline;
}

Comment: @AndresIlich, with three big errors, his CSS should not work at all.

Comment: @Sparky672 should have worked looking at it from the `position:fixed` side of things, anyways.

Comment: @AndresIlich, except for the fact that there are no specified coordinates for `position:fixed`.  It's a jumbled mess that totally depends on the browser to fill in the blanks and ignore the contradictory rules.  I guess we just have different definitions of what "works".

Comment: @Sparky672 "Right column fixed position works on Opera & Firefox but not on Chrome" was mostly referencing to that, it is weird that it does not work in Chrome alone. Maybe he didn't post enough code? But yes, i hear what you are saying.

Comment: @AndresIlich, not weird at all.  Every browser is going to interpret non-compliant code differently; this is why we follow compliance standards.

Comment: @Sparky672 still find it weird though, a test case would have helped me look at the *why* of it all, compliance aside.

Comment: @AndresIlich, when code is non-compliant, the browser must try to "figure it out" in order to render _something_.  Every browser was written by a unique team and is based on a rendering engine.  Every rending engine is written by another team.  What's so weird about random code rendering in an unpredictable fashion?  If it was predictable, then it would be following a Standard.  Since the user's code is not following the Standard rules, what else would you possibly expect the browser to do?  I agree with your implication that the question is poorly written and lacking information.

Comment: @Sparky672 i've reported webkit bugs before and always looking for more, i guess i just needed to nitpick the issue (always hunting for bugs), but i understand what you are saying. Chrome is one of the smarter browsers out there and i found it weird that it was the only one not functioning as the rest, even with non-compliant code.

Comment: @AndresIlich, I could also argue that Chrome was functioning perfectly by ignoring that bad code.

Comment: @Sparky672 that is correct, although browsers have babied HTML and allowed non-compliance to *at least* function in all browsers, to some degree. What some may call "working code". Urghh, tough.

Answer (score 14):

1)  Firstly, remove `display: inline` because, if you want the block-level element to be `position: fixed`, you cannot also have it `inline`.  A [`fixed` position element is outside the normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning) and therefore, by definition, cannot also be inline.

2)  Secondly, remove `float: right` since you want it `fixed`.  [According to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo), it can't be both.

[*"...if 'position' has the value 'absolute' or 'fixed', the box is absolutely positioned, the computed value of 'float' is 'none'..." ~ W3C spec*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)

3)  And finally, when using `absolute` or `fixed` (`fixed` is a subset of `absolute` [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning)), set a position of the element by adding something like `top: 0;` and `right: 0;` which places it with respect to the edges of its parent.

```
#rightcolumn { 
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; <-- adjust accordingly
    right: 0; <-- adjust accordingly
}
```

Here is the [Visual Formatting Model spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html).

Comment: Additionally, an `overflow:hidden` or `transform:whatever` on a parent element prevents the element to be fixed / sticky.

Answer (score 6):

According to the spec fixed means The element is positioned relative to the browser window.  but you're not specifying any (top,right,left,bottom) so it knows where to sit in the window.  Try specifying the actual position.

Answer (score 1):

You can't float and fix a position on an element and expect it to work. Also, you have not declared where you want the element fixed because you have no `top`, `left`, `right`, or `bottom` in your CSS.

Remove the float, add positioning (`top`, `left`, `right`, or `bottom`), and it should work just fine.

```
<div id="rightcolumn">
<p>blah blah blah</p>
</div>

#rightcolumn { 
margin: 0px;
top:0;
right:0; /*places div in top right corner and stays there even when you scroll!*/
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: bold;
height: auto;
width: 300px;
position: fixed;
}
```

You now have a 300px width box place in the top right hand corner of the browser. Unless you're using IE6 or 7, won't work there.

Answer (score 1):

Also check if the wrapper has enabled hardware acceleration by having `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`